# ggplot is exporting empty images

Tags: r, image, ggplot2

I am exporting plots as `png` files. I am exporting plots individually then using grid.arrange to export plots together. The `grid.arrange` exports `png` files just fine, however saving plots individually returns and empty image in the same folder. The image is actually the plot size but graph/titles are apparent. The code below shows how I am plotting.

```
########## Cy5 individual plots############

png(file='10pMcomp_plots/DNA01_Cy5_10pM.png',width=600,height=600,res=100)
AllCy5MeansDNA1bind10pMwithoutcontrols<-melt(AllCy5MeansDNA1bind10pMwithoutcontrols, id=c("Spot_Size","Molarity","Mean Fluorescence"))
DNA1Cy5_10pm<-ggplot(AllCy5MeansDNA1bind10pMwithoutcontrols, aes(x=as.factor(Molarity), y=AllCy5MeansDNA1bind10pMwithoutcontrols$Mean, fill=Spot_Size)) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + ylab("Mean Fluorescence") + ylim(0,650)  +xlab("Molarity (uM)") + ggtitle("Trimmed Mean of Cy5 Fluorescence \n with DNA 01 probe.")+ theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 15))
dev.off()

png(file='10pMcomp_plots/DNA02_Cy5_10pM.png',width=600,height=600,res=100)
AllCy5MeansDNA2bind10pMwithoutcontrols<-melt(AllCy5MeansDNA2bind10pMwithoutcontrols, id=c("Spot_Size","Molarity","Mean Fluorescence"))
DNA2Cy5_10pm<-ggplot(AllCy5MeansDNA2bind10pMwithoutcontrols, aes(x=as.factor(Molarity), y=AllCy5MeansDNA2bind10pMwithoutcontrols$Mean, fill=Spot_Size)) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + ylab("Mean Fluorescence") + ylim(0,650)  + xlab("Molarity (uM)") + ggtitle("Trimmed Mean of Cy5 Fluorescence \n with DNA 02 probe. ")+ theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 15))
dev.off()

png(file='10pMcomp_plots/DNA01_Cy5_10pM.png',width=600,height=600,res=100)
AllCy5MeansDNA19bind10pMwithoutcontrols<-melt(AllCy5MeansDNA19bind10pMwithoutcontrols, id=c("Spot_Size","Molarity","Mean Fluorescence"))
DNA19Cy5_10pm<-ggplot(AllCy5MeansDNA19bind10pMwithoutcontrols, aes(x=as.factor(Molarity), y=AllCy5MeansDNA19bind10pMwithoutcontrols$Mean, fill=Spot_Size)) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + ylab("Mean Fluorescence") + ylim(0,650)  +xlab("Molarity (uM)") + ggtitle("Trimmed Mean of Cy5 Fluorescence \n with DNA 19 probe.")+ theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 15))
dev.off()

png(file='10pMcomp_plots/DNA02_Cy5_10pM.png',width=600,height=600,res=100)
AllCy5MeansDNA20bind10pMwithoutcontrols<-melt(AllCy5MeansDNA20bind10pMwithoutcontrols, id=c("Spot_Size","Molarity","Mean Fluorescence"))
DNA20Cy5_10pm<-ggplot(AllCy5MeansDNA20bind10pMwithoutcontrols, aes(x=as.factor(Molarity), y=AllCy5MeansDNA20bind10pMwithoutcontrols$Mean, fill=Spot_Size)) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + ylab("Mean Fluorescence") + ylim(0,650)  + xlab("Molarity (uM)") + ggtitle("Trimmed Mean of Cy5 Fluorescence \n with DNA 20 probe.")+ theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 15))
dev.off()

#########ARRAY OF PLOTS#############
png(file='10pMcomp_plots/Cy5_10pM.png',width=800,height=800,res=100)

grid.arrange(DNA1Cy5_10pm, DNA2Cy5_10pm, DNA19Cy5_10pm, DNA20Cy5_10pm, ncol=2, main =  "Cy5 Fluorescence with 10pM complement" )
dev.off()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `print(DNA1Cy5_10pm)`, etc.

Comment: I'm quite sure what you mean by duplicate of ggplot's qplot?

Comment: Take a look at the question above, it has the same problem as you and the answer is given there that will likely help. That is what "possible duplicate" means.

Comment: Ah thank you, I'm still new to SO.